# Insert a line brak before a special character inside a block of text using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am importing xml-file from a JUnit Test report and applying some css styling to it using xslt. The problem I am trying to solve is how to get the proper line breaks as when I'm vying it in a text editor instead of a long line och text only broken by the width of the browser window. As of now the xslt code I'm using looks like this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="testsuite/testcase">
      <div class="testsuit">
          <div class="testcase">
               <h3>
                   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </h3>
                <div class="result">
                    <xsl:value-of select="system-out"/>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

An example of the xml looks like this

```
<testsuite errors="0" failures="0" name="testsuite" skipped="0" tests="7">
    <testcase name="foo-bar2_1" time="3.6">
        <system-out># ** lorem_ipsum = 0 # Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo_bar_004 # ** Note: lorem_ips: generic FOOBAR_FILTER = 0 # Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo_bar_004# ** Note: foo_bar_001: generic IPSUM_DESCRIPTORS = 0 # Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0
        </system-out>
    </testcase>
</testsuit>
```

I would like to add a line break before each '#' that makes the browser display the text properly like this.

# ** lorem_ipsum = 0 
# Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo_bar_004
 
# ** Note: lorem_ips: generic FOOBAR_FILTER = 0
# Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /foo_bar_004
# ** Note: foo_bar_001: generic IPSUM_DESCRIPTORS = 0 
# Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor? Or is that client-side XSLT 1.0?

Comment: "*how to get the proper line breaks as when I'm vying it in a text editor*" I don't see any line breaks when I view this in a text editor. What am I missing?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have a separate .xml file that might contain trade secrets from the company that I work for so (at least it says so in the beginning of the file). I manually tried to simulate how it looked. But when I open the original file in everything from OsX text editor to Sublime Text and Notepad ++ it gets proper line breaks.

Comment: I am not sure how to help you when you don't show us an equivalent of your real input. You also haven't answered the question about your XSLT version.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I'm new to this but I'm doing all this in the browser and as I understand no when I tried to find out the answer to your question, Firefox, Chrome and so on does not support XSLT 2.0. So I guess the answer to your question is client-side XSLT 1.0. If so, it also explains why I can't get your solution to work.

Considering that my system-out tag contains a large chunk of text (sometimes thousands of rows), and I want to alter the raw data in this tag, I might be better of trying to solve this by parsing the text with for example PHP instead of XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0 I would suggest to use `analyze-string`

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="testsuite/testcase">
          <div class="testsuit">
              <div class="testcase">
                   <h3>
                       <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </h3>
                    <ul class="result">
                        <xsl:analyze-string select="system-out" regex="#[^#]*">
                            <xsl:matching-substring>
                                <li>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </li>
                            </xsl:matching-substring>
                        </xsl:analyze-string>
                    </ul>
                </div>
           </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I tried your solution during the weekend but can't get it to work so I made a gist of my complete code.

https://gist.github.com/MarkusDNC/973d05924bb200cfed9c21ab06cb4e80

Comment: You would need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor to get it to work, see http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEux where the transformation is done using Saxon 9.